# how to get [ current_path ] in shell bash prompt?

Tags: bash, shell, path, display

Is it possible to have the name of the current working directory in the prompt in shell ?

Im working on OSX and CentOS in multiple projects under /srv/... and a mistake for wrong directory is quickly made.

I would like to have

[current_path] in my prompt somehow , perhaps coloured
Is this possible?

For example  like /srv/myproject it would give prompt [root@server [myproject]# 
This should stay the same even in /srv/myproject/app/etc

Comment: If you're in `/srv/myproject/app/etc/` then how should it determine that you want to see `[myproject]` instead of `[app]` or `[etc]`?

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be close to what you're looking for:

```
PS1="\$([[ \$PWD == /srv/*/* ]] && p=\${PWD#/*/} && p=[\${p%%/*}]; echo -n \"\$p$ \" )"
```

For testing, use this to show the full directory along with the truncated one for comparison:

```
PS1="\$([[ \$PWD == /srv/*/* ]] && p=\${PWD#/*/} && p=[\${p%%/*}]; echo -n \"[\$PWD] \$p$ \" )"
```

The escapes cause the variable expansion to be deferred until the prompt is issued. The parameter expansions strip off the first level directory and all directory levels below the second level.

You will probably need:

```
shopt -s promptvars
```

but I think it's the default.

The prompt only does its job when you're in a directory under `/srv`

This is one way to add some color. It makes the project name cyan.

```
PS1="\$([[ \$PWD == /srv/*/* ]] && p=\${PWD#/*/} && p='[\[\033[1;36m\]'\${p%%/*}'\[\033[0m\]]'; echo -n \"\$p$ \" )"
```

Answer (score 2):

The character sequence for the full current working directory in `$PS1` is `\w`. See ["Tip: Prompt magic"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following string in `/etc/bashrc` on my Linux systems. Usually it's a matter of replacing an upper-case "W" with lower-case "w" on most default Bash installations:

```
PS1="[\u@\h \w]\\$ "
```

This yields:

```
[root@MDMarra /ppro/edi/0010/GOODBI/receive/archive]#
```

instead of:

```
[root@MDMarra archive]#
```

Comment: thank you but i ment more like /srv/myproject it would give prompt [root@server [myproject]#

Comment: The "w" option will show the FULL path... See my update.

Comment: I pop up everywhere!